# Using `find` to find pom.xml file and do a maven build, ignoring nested POMs

Tags: bash, shell

I currently have a couple of applications with different folder structures. I am using `maven` for building these apps. I am running into some issues. At times the main `pom.xml` file is in the root directory and other times it is in the sub-directory. I only want to do a maven build with the main `pom.xml` found in the main/highest directory. I am running the `find` command from `workspace`(below for more details). How could I achieve this without depending on the folder structure?

Shell Command:

```
find * -maxdepth 1 -name pom.xml -execdir mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \;
```

This works with this folder structure:

```
workspace
|-- app1
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |-- abrt.conf
|   |-- gpg_keys
|   `-- web
|       |-- pom.xml
|       `-- test.conf
```

returns:

```
app1/pom.xml
```

The command does returns a couple of `pom.xml` files with this folder structure:

```
workspace
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |-- abrt.conf
|   |-- gpg_keys
|   `-- web
|       |-- pom.xml
|       `-- test.conf
```

returns:

```
web/pom.xml
pom.xml
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current setup? What is your desired output?

Comment: Use `find` to just find the `pom.xml` files, then assign the first one to a variable and use its directory. The first one will be in the highest directory level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `find` operates breadth-first unless explicitly told to do otherwise, the first result will always be the shallowest. Thus, you just need to tell it to quit after finding a single POM file.

In GNU `find`, there's a `-quit` action for exactly this purpose:

```
find . -name pom.xml \
  -execdir mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \; \
  -quit
```

If you aren't guaranteed to have GNU `find`, but *are* guaranteed to have bash, you can read just the first result and operate on that:

```
if IFS= read -r -d '' pom_filename < <(find . -name pom.xml -print0); then
  (cd -- "${pom_filename%/*}" && exec mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true)
fi
```

Note the use of `-print0` -- that way we avoid maliciously-named directories (with newlines) being able to influence behavior by injecting extra names into the list.

---

Now, let's consider a trickier case:

```
A/pom.xml
A/sub/pom.xml
B/pom.xml
B/sub/pom.xml
```

If you want to run for *both* A and B, but not A/sub or B/sub, then things get a bit more interesting:

```
find . \
    -type d -exec test -e '{}/pom.xml' ';' \
    -execdir mvn clean pkg ... ';' \
    -prune
```

Note that we're using `-prune` to tell `find` to stop recursing into any directory where a `pom.xml` exists, but only after we already ran a build there.

Comment: This Charles Duffy guy knows his stuff.  I was digging through the man page looking for an option like this, but I missed it. Have an up-vote!

Comment: Thanks! BTW, re: missing it yourself, could be you were looking on a BSD platform -- MacOS, for example, doesn't ship `-quit` in their default `find` (though if you have GNU coreutils via MacPorts or such, it's available via `gfind` there).

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `find` without the `*` (replace with `.` as suggested in comment) to list from highest directory to the lowest.  Pipe to `head -1` to get the first one of the list.  Put all of this into a command substitution (`$(...)`) to assign a variable.  Run the same command with your variable instead.  Since you may have `/` in the file name now, we will not need `-name`, `-maxdepth` or `*`.

```
pomxmlfile="$(find . -name pom.xml | head -1)"
find "$pomxmlfile" -execdir mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \;
```

Comment: POSIX `find` *requires* at least one argument to start at; being able to leave that out entirely is a GNUism. For portability's sake, then, it's better to use `find .` than just bare `find`.

Answer (score 0):

This line finds the `pom.xml` with the shortest path (ie the pom nearest the top of the directory tree) and executes `mvn` from its directory:

```
find . -name pom.xml | awk '{print length($0) " " $0}' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | head -n 1 | xargs -I {} bash -c 'cd $(dirname {}) && mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.error.ignore=true -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true \;'
```

Pipe chain breakdown:

- finds all `pom.xml` under current directory
- adds length of line to start of line
- sorts lines by number (ie the length) lowest first
- removes the length
- keeps only the first (ie shortest) line
- runs `mvn` from the directory of the `pom.xml` file

Comment: Substituting into sh -c '...' or bash -c '...' means malicious filenames (well, directory names, in this case, since the filenames are fixed) can run arbitrary code. It's much, **much** safer to `-exec bash -c '... "$1" ...' _ {} ';'`, keeping the data (the filename) out of band from the code, and passing it on the shell's argument list, not substituted into text parsed as code.

Comment: ...or, with `xargs`, to just leave off the `-I` or `-J` arguments altogether and use the default behavior of appending content to EOL; note that to make xargs use safe with directory names that could contain spaces/quotes/etc, it's also necessary to use extensions such as `-d $'\n'` (if you're sure names can't contain newlines) or `-0` (to be safe in all cases; obvs., requires prior pipeline components to be modified appropriately).

Comment: ...so, `find . -name pom.xml -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' name; do printf '%s\t%s\0' "${#name}" "$name"; done | sort -z -n | head -z -n 1 | xargs -0 bash -c 'cd -- "$(dirname -- "$1")" && mvn clean package' _` would be one safer way to write the above, if on a platform with GNU `sort` and `head`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. If the main `pom.xml` is in a directory `a/b/c` and no other `pom.xml` is in a subdirectory below `a` other than `a/b/c`, then the main `pom.xml` must have the shortest path string. So in that case I guess this command brings up the `pom.xml` closest to root and can be executed from either `a`, `a/b`, or `a/b/c`:

```
find -name pom.xml | awk 'NR==1 || length() < length(s) { s = $0 } END { print s }'
```